# How to calculate average using group with field existence check in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and trying to calculate the average seen count for my app.

Collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: "478",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "101"
  },
  {
    _id: "991",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "101"
  },
  {
    _id: "125",
    status: "unseen",
    userId: "101"
  },
  {
    _id: "663",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "112"
  },
  {
    _id: "778",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "112"
  },{
    _id: "452",
    status: "seen",
    personId: "113"
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[{
    seenCount : 2,
    unSeenCount : 1,
    averageSeenCount : 66.66
}]
```

There are 3 `userIds`(101,112 and 113) in my collection out of which, two users (112 and 113) have seen the messages everytime they got notified and userId 101 has unseen one message.
Now I need to get the count of such users who have seen all the messages, who have missed atleast one and the `averageSeenCount`. `i.e., (2/2+1)*100 = 66.66.`
There is one more thing I need to take care of that is, for some documents instead of `userId`, I have `personId`. So, I need to first check if there is a field by name `userId` then group by `userId` or else group by `personId`. I tried using `$cond` for this but it is not working.
Really appreciate the help.

Comment: mate that condition of person and user is just annoying

Comment: Hi @Minsky, Yes even I am bit annoyed by this condition but I my collection few documents has this kind of structure. Can we do something like if userId exists then group by that else group by personId?

Comment: I'm on it but cant find a way so far, the rest is not impossible

Comment: think I solved it, give 10'

Comment: maybe 15 more XD

Comment: @sinr does the answer help you?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks a ton  :) @varman. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do like following

- `$addFields` We overwrite / newly create `userId` based on existence of `userId`
- `$sort` to give a priority to **unseen**. If a user has atleast one unseen, he is counted as unseen user
- Since we used `userId` and `status` in `sort`, we need to get the first data using `$group`
- Again group it to conditional count of **seenCount** and **unseenCount** with the help of `$sum` and `$cond`
- Finally we perform calculation part as you already mentioned `(2/2+1)*100` using `$multiply`, `$divide` and `$add`

Her is the script

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  "$addFields": {
    "userId": { $ifNull: ["$userId", "$personId"]}
  }
}, 
{ $sort: { userId: 1, status: -1 } }, 
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$userId",
    status: {
      $first: "$status"
    }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    seenCount: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "seen"]},
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    unseenCount: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "unseen"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$addFields": {
    averageSeenCount: {
      "$multiply": [
            {
                "$divide": ["$seenCount", 
                    { "$add": ["$seenCount", "$unseenCount"]}
                    ]},
        100
      ]
    }
  }
}])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uFFQCmpwQmi)**

Comment: Hi @varman... can you please help on this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64924624/14197908

Comment: @sinr i will have a look and try to help

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one

#### Result            \ * _ * /

```
[
  {
    "avSeen": 66.66,
    "seenAll": 2,
    "unseenOneOrMore": 1
  }
]
```

### →[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZLmxZKccd-T) ←

---

**Explanations**

1. Group according to the user/person field (separately)
2. For each group, split fields between seen and unseen
3. Count seen if unseen=0; Count unseen if unseen>0
4. averages

**Pipeline**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: [
          "$$ROOT.userId",
          {
            userId: "$userId"
          },
          {
            personId: "$personId"
          }
        ]
      },
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      seen: {
        $filter: {
          "input": "$docs",
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$d.status",
              "seen"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      unseen: {
        $filter: {
          "input": "$docs",
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$d.status",
              "unseen"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      seenAll: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    {
                      $size: "$seen"
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    {
                      $size: "$unseen"
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      unseenOneOrMore: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $ne: [
                {
                  $size: "$unseen"
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "seenAll": 1,
      "unseenOneOrMore": 1,
      _id: 0,
      avSeen: {
        $trunc: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              {
                $divide: [
                  "$seenAll",
                  {
                    $sum: [
                      "$seenAll",
                      "$unseenOneOrMore"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              100
            ]
          },
          2
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  }
])
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions work, but can be very consuming due to multiple $group stages.
Working with [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operators, you can achieve this in only two stages :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      seen: {
        $addToSet: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "seen",
                "$status"
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$userId",
                "$personId"
              ]
            },
            else: "$$REMOVE"
          }
        }
      },
      unseen: {
        $addToSet: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "unseen",
                "$status"
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$userId",
                "$personId"
              ]
            },
            else: "$$REMOVE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      seenAll: {
        $size: {
          "$setDifference": [
            "$seen",
            "$unseen"
          ]
        }
      },
      unseenOneOrMore: {
        $size: "$unseen"
      },
      averageSeenCount: {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              {
                $size: {
                  "$setDifference": [
                    "$seen",
                    "$unseen"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                $size: {
                  $setUnion: [
                    "$seen",
                    "$unseen"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The result will be the following :

```
[
  {
    "averageSeenCount": 66.66666666666666,
    "seenAll": 2,
    "unseenOneOrMore": 1
  }
]
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zs-I3PwlrBJ)